# Confusion about navigation and navigation experimental

Tags: ros, navigation, sbpl, move-base, pathplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi together,

I am pretty new to pathplanning and navigation in general and especially with ROS.
So for now my goal is to use the SBPL_Lattice_Planner as global planner and another planner as local planner.
My problem is that I downloaded the sbpl lattice planner fork from [TU-Darmstadt](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/sbpl_lattice_planner.git) and built it in my workspace with the sbpl package, which I got from [here](https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl.git). (see below for "full" workspace configuration)

After struggling with it for I while, I noticed that the sbpl planner is included in the navigation_experimental package. So do I have to use the experimental package? Or is it possible to get it to work as I configured my workspace?

My workspaceconfig looks like this:

- catkin_ws

  - src

    - navigation
    - my_robot_2dnav
    - sbpl
    - sbpl_lattice_planner

and I am trying to get the planner to work with the following lines in my `move_base.launch`:

```
<param name="base_global_planer" value="sbpl_lattice_planner/SBPLLatticePlanner" />
<param name="SBPLLatticePlanner/planner_type" value="AD*" />
<param name="SBPLLatticePlanner/primitive_filename" value="/home/aschultz/temp_ws/src/sbpl/matlab/mprim/pr2_all_2.5cm_20turncost.mprim" />
```

Is this all the right way to go?

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231795/confusion-about-navigation-and-navigation-experimental/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 232 on 2016-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

navigation_experimental just grouped a bunch of other packages, where some depended on each other. If you managed to compile your SBPL_Lattice_Planner without errors, it should work without the need of the navigation_experimental metapackage.

use the command  `rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nav_core` to verify which planners you have available to work with.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2016-04-13**:
rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nav_core

```
sbpl_lattice_planner /home/aschultz/temp_ws/src/sbpl_lattice_planner/bgp_plugin.xml
```

It seems it is in the list. So it means I am able to use it. I the `move_base.launch` correct?
Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-04-13**:
I've never used that planner, so I cannot tell it for sure, but it seems correct to me. You definitely have  the plugin available, so give it a try!

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2016-04-13**:
Okay but when i look at `rostopic list` I just see my local planner and this output `/move_base/NavfnROS/plan` which is a global planner I guess. But the output of  `rostopic list` should also outout something from sbpl isn't it? As it should provide a global plan topic.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-04-13**:
this is only a visualization topic, although it's weird that you are seeing it. Not sure if sbpl also publishes such a topic.... can you post your complete launch file and config files, please?

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2016-04-25**:
Hey, sorry for the late answer. The problem was, a wrongly sourced workspace :/ Thanks for your help!!!